# how to resize the margins on my box model to fit on a mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to html and I'm not very experienced when using the box model. On desktop my website looks how I want it to, but on mobile it looks subpar. Can anyone help me out? thanks!

here's my webpage that's messed up:
https://lilypad9000.neocities.org/home2.html

here's my code:

```
<style>

a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: DarkOrchid;
  width: 200px;
}
h1 {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 230px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
div {
  background-color: #330033;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid #32174D;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
</style>
```

thank you, sorry if this question was already asked, I couldn't find a clear answer :p.

Comment: start here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_get_current_window.asp

Comment: I'd start with [setting the viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and then use  [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a @media query {//everything inside in here} or a @container queries {//everything inside in here} I'd recommend you look at a couple tutorials or lesson though

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries, see the following example

```
@media (max-width: 667px) {
  div {
     // put whatever style you want
  }
}
```

I put 667px as an example, it's mean when the window starts from 667px and less than that do the following style

if you want to put a style between different screen size you can follow the following example

```
@media (min-width: 667px) and (min-width: 400px) {
  div {
     // put whatever style you want
  }
}
```

See this [article](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/) it's very helpful